# Create avl tree where each node points to another avl tree

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I have the following input txt file

```
   id    element
    0    1
    0    3
    1    0
    1    1
    1    3
    2    2
    2    4
    3    4
    4    1
```

I want to organize the data into AVL tree. My first thought was to create an AVL tree of IDs and then each of the ID nodes in the first tree would contain a pointer to another AVL tree where the elements would be stored.

Then I thought I could do this by creating an AVL tree of pointers to nodes this ID is linked to. That means I have to add another pointer to node to every node of my tree. That additional pointer would be linked to a tree that contains nodes containing pointers to nodes of my primary tree containing demanded linked ID.

Following is my methods for AVL tree where they work fine. In struct avl_node_id I thought I would add a pointer to the root of the other AVL tree. However I don't know how to actually implement all this.

```
class AVLTree
{
    public:
        AVLTree();
        void readFile();
        void printToScreen();

        struct avl_node
        {
            int data;
            struct avl_node *left;
            struct avl_node *right;
        }*root;

        struct avl_node_id
        {
            struct avl_node **root;
            int data;
            struct avl_node *left;
            struct avl_node *right;
        }*id_root;

        int height(avl_node *);
        int diff(avl_node *);
        avl_node *rr_rotation(avl_node *);
        avl_node *ll_rotation(avl_node *);
        avl_node *lr_rotation(avl_node *);
        avl_node *rl_rotation(avl_node *);
        avl_node* balance(avl_node *);
        avl_node* insert(avl_node *, int );
        void display(avl_node *, int);
        void inorder(avl_node *);
    private:
        int n,m;
};
```

And here is the code to read file and insert IDs into initial tree

```
void AVLTree::readFile()
{
    ifstream read("input2.txt");
    while(read>>n>>m){
        id_root = insert(id_root, n);
    }
}

AVLTree::avl_node *AVLTree::insert(avl_node *root, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new avl_node;
        root->data = value;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    else if (value < root->data)
    {
        root->left = insert(root->left, value);
        root = balance (root);
    }
    else if (value > root->data)
    {
        root->right = insert(root->right, value);
        root = balance (root);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: why cannot you use `std::multimap<int, int>` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have to use AVL trees.

Comment: this should be helpful then: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/